# jsf param doesn't clear after downloading a content

Tags: java, jsf, parameters, primefaces, download

when I download a content, clicking on the primefaces commandButton, I set a jsf parameter useful for required fields validation.
After that download is completed, if I clear some required field value and I click on an another commandButton that doesn't pass the jsf parameter to trigger the validation, the validation is triggered and it fails.
Here the example jsf code:

```
<p:inputTextarea value="#{flowScope.inputText}" required="#{not empty param.includeInSave)}" requiredMessage="Required Input Text" />
                                    
<p:commandButton id="add_table_row" value="Call action without validation" action="add_table_row" update=":table_pnl" />

<p:commandButton id="download_pdf" value="Download" action="download_pdf" ajax="false" onclick="if(!confirm('Start download?')) return false;">
     <f:param name="includeInSave" value="true" />

<p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="save" ajax="false" onclick="if(!confirm('Save?')) return false;">
     <f:param name="includeInSave" value="true" />
</p:commandButton>
```

So when I click on "download_pdf" the validation is triggered and it works.
After I clear the inputTextarea value and I click on "add_table_row" commandButton, but the action has still the includeInSave param in the request, because the validation si triggered again.
This thing doesn't happen if I click on "save" commandButton, that is identical in jsf code, but it doesn't download a file in the java code.
So I think that I have to set something difference in the HttpServletResponse in java

In the java code I will download the file in this way:

```
public static Boolean downloadBytes(byte[] bytes, String name, String mimeType, RequestContext requestContext) {
     
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) requestContext.getExternalContext().getNativeResponse();
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(bytes.length));
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int size = 4096;
        int i = 0;
        while(i  < bytes.length)
        {
            int max_range = Math.min(i + size, bytes.length);
            byte[] mini_buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, i, max_range);
            i+= size;       
            outputStream.write(mini_buf);
        }
        
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    } finally {  
        try {  
            if (outputStream != null) {  
                outputStream.close();  
            }  
        } catch (IOException err) {  
            err.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I hope that someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide versions used?

Comment: my jsf version is 2.1.7